# issue and error message : Couldn't find School with 'id'=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

What I want to achieve is that list each member with schools and thereafter list Schools with all belonging members. Schools can have many members and members can have many schools also. I have the following set up in the system, but have problems finding the solution for it. Here it is how my code looks like:

controller:

```
class MembersController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_school

  def index
    @members = Member.all
  end

  def new
    @member = Member.new
  end

  def create
    @member = Member.new(member_params)
    @member.school = @school 
    @member.save
    redirect_to members_path
  end


  private

  def set_school
    @school = School.find(params[:school])
  end

  def member_params
    params.require(:member).permit(:name, :email,:school)
  end
end
```

This is my route:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'schools/index'

  resources :members
  resources :school

end
```

My view looks like:

```
<% @members.each do |member| %>
  <%= member.name %>
  <%= member.email %>
  <%= member.school %>
<% end %>
```

model for members:

```
class CreateMembers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :members do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
```

my School model :

```
class CreateSchools < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :schools do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
```

and the reference:

```
class AddSchoolRefToMembers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_reference :members, :school, foreign_key: true
  end
```

Any help would be great! Thank you!

Comment: how should the url look like for your new action ? is it `example.com/members/new?school=someid` or just `example.com/members/new` ?

Comment: example.com/members/new

Comment: @ashvin `resources :members` does allow query paramaters :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<%= simple_form_for [@member] do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %> 
  <%= f.input :email %> 
  <%= f.collection_select :school_id, School.all, :id, :name %> 
  <%= f.submit %> 
<% end %>
```

Change the strong params

```
def member_params
  params.require(:member).permit(:name, :email, :school_id)
end
```

And you can remove the `before_action :set_school`

Also you need to change the action as school_id is already in params

```
def create
  @member = Member.create(member_params)
  redirect_to members_path
end
```

Comment: Thanks Deepak, but how do you pass value in there? I have in my seed file the values of schools
Member.create!([{ name: 'Star Wars' }, { email: 'star.wars@gmail.com' }])
School.create!(name: 'Westminster')
School.create!(name: 'UCL')
School.create!(name: 'City')

Comment: @imocsari `f.select` will get the school from the user :)

Comment: After your edited answer params for school will be `params[:member][:school]`

Comment: @DeepakMahakale Yes now its better

Comment: the comments on puneet's answer worth checking, OP already has `f.collection_select :school`

Comment: I changed all of those above, still get "undefined method `school=' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: @imocsari have you changed the `create` method? have you removed the `before_action`? have you changed the `member_params` method

Comment: @imocsari now no need for `set_school` method, change your params method to add school_id param

Answer (score 2):

You have set before_action for all actions in controller. For, index and new there is no school_id, so you have to run before_action only for create.

Change below code

```
before_action :set_school
```

to

```
before_action :set_school, only: ['create']
```

Comment: OP may want to pass school in query paramaters :)

Comment: On create action, you have to pass school in parameter.

Comment: I changed it, but now got the following: undefined method `school=' for nil:NilClass

Comment: you have to pass school id in params[:school]

Comment: Have you added association in Member and school model?

Comment: @imocsari create actions are normally for POST requests and so a `<form>` must exist with the fields you need(including an `<input>` for school), if you don't want to make `school` as input then you need to explain more about what you want and what you're trying to achieve

Comment: @puneet18, I hav association in the model: have_many member in school.rb and belongs_to school in member.rb

Comment: @niceman, this is my new.html.erb: 
<%= simple_form_for [@member] do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :email %>
  <%= f.collection_select :school, School.all, :id, :name %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

Comment: What I want to achieve is that list each member with schools and thereafter list Schools with all belonging members. Schools can have many members and members can have many schools also.

Comment: @imocsari your last comment deserves to be added to your question, as to the issue hmmmm

Comment: or you can add school_id in member_params

Comment: @imocsari `<%= simple_form_for @member do |f|` would do, no need to wrap `@member` in array, but I don't think that's the cause

Comment: Thanks, changed it, still the same error "undefined method `school=' for nil:NilClass"
class MembersController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_school, only: ['create']
    def index
     @members = Member.all
     @member.school = @school 
    end
    def new
      @member = Member.new
    end

Comment: @imocsari dude why are you not removing ` before_action :set_school` and why do you have `@member.school = @school` in index action

Comment: Thanks, has been removed. However now the school displayed as #<School:0x00559ebaab3c28>, I added <%= member.school %> to the index

Answer (score 0):

@imocsari to get the name of school change your view like

```
<% @members.each do |member| %>
 <%= member.name %>
 <%= member.email %>
 <%= member.school.try(:name) %>
<% end %>
```

`member.school` will give you associated school of member with all column, if you want to show name of school this is way `member.school.try(:name) or member.school.name`

`member.school.try(:name)` this will return nil if there is not any school for member, It will by pass exception

`member.school.name` this will raise error if there is not any school for member.